# JavaFX multi-line label right justification line break alignment

Tags: javafx, alignment, label, right-justified

I have a JavaFX interface with some multi-line text labels which are right justified using the usual settings.

What's bothering me is that the right justification is line breaking after a space instead of what I thought would be the normal of breaking at the end of the final character of the first line, which gives it a ragged right edge.

Just checked and I'm not mad, in Excel for example it breaks where I would expect and gives a clean right edge.

So...  assuming this is a bug or lack of attention to detail by the JavaFX team, is there anything I can override in Label to fix this problem ??

The first image is the JavaFX version, second Excel.

[image: JavaFX Label right alignment]

[image: Excel right alignment]

Comment: Just to understand, you're talking about the Alignment of your text in the 2nd line of your `Label` ? example of text : (**Successful Trades**) !

Comment: Can you post code that produces this result? (Presumably you don't actually need a table here: just a label will do.) What do you consider to be the "usual settings" you refer to in your question?

Comment: To clarify, for example on Successful Trades item, what I want is for the L of Successful to be directly above the S of Trades, like it shows in Excel and every other right justification system.  There is no table involved, its just a Label with wrap text set to true and right justified.  Currently on all the examples, there is a space character shown at the end of the first line.

Comment: This is indeed interesting. It looks like JavaFX keeps displaying the "space" between the words when wrap is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is already reported as [JDK-8145496](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145496) and right now is **not targeted** for any specific release.

It is reported as a P4 priority. Feel free to vote for the issue, if you want to get it fixed with a higher priority.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have opened another question about how to make a patch.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405290/patching-a-bug-in-the-jdk-for-an-individual-application   I'll leave this one as unanswered for now to see if anyone else has any ideas for a workaround.